# What is this 20-pin industrial connector?

Tags: identification, connector, power-connector

I'm upgrading some pretty old (1975) industrial equipment and this exact connector is on the back panel of the control device. It's rectangular in shape, has 20 flat pins and its overall dimensions are 24 mm x 104 mm.

What type/model can it be?

[image: photo of connector]

[image: photo of connector]

[image: drawing of connector dimensions]

Comment: It might help to list what actual equipment this is found on.

Comment: Pull it out & look for a manufacturer name/logo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DIN41622 connector 20-pin male

Comment: Just found out its model by coincidence and remembered my question here. And, of course, your answer confirms my finding.